# ReactNative Android -- Unable to create application (SoLoader Resource deadlock)

Tags: android, react-native, deadlock, ioexception, runtimeexception

Can't reproduce it, but see these crashlogs in Crashlytics in some of my apps.

RN 0.61.5 at one of app and 0.59.9 at another

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException

Unable to create application *.MainApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Resource deadlock would occur

android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication + 6288 (ActivityThread.java:6288)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 975 (ZygoteInit.java:975)

Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
java.io.IOException: Resource deadlock would occur

com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.init + 192 (SoLoader.java:192)
*.MainApplication.onCreate + 119 (MainApplication.java:119)
android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate + 1158 (Instrumentation.java:1158)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 975 (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

MainApplication.java:119 ->

```
SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
```

Any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: are you using app bundle. I think there are some bugs in app bundles for android

Comment: @HarishJangra yeah, im using app bundle. Do u think separate apks will fix it?

Comment: Yes that will for sure solve the problem of so loader

Comment: @HarishJangra starting from august 2021 app bundle is required. What to do with this then?

Comment: I think they had fixed it in latest versions for react-native and soloader. Check their github issues for the same

Comment: @HarishJangra nope. same issue on last react-native version (0.64.0)